# creating object pools of different proeprties files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

How can i create two object pools using two properties files? Currently i have it working using one properties file.

### ConnectionsFactory.java

```
public class ConnectionsFactory implements PoolableObjectFactory {

  private Properties connectionProperties;
  public ConnectionsFactory(Properties connectionProperties) {
      this.connectionProperties= connectionProperties;
  }

 //here makeObject, destroyObject and validateObject methods have been overridden

}
```

### ConnectionPool.java

```
public class ConnectionPool {
 private GenericObjectPool objectPool; .
 private int maxActive = 50;
 private int maxIdle = -1;
 public SiperianClientPool(SiperianClientFactory factory) {
    this.objectPool = new GenericObjectPool();
    this.objectPool.setFactory(factory);
    this.objectPool.setWhenExhaustedAction(GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK);
    this.objectPool.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    this.objectPool.setTestOnReturn(true);
    this.objectPool.setMaxActive(this.maxActive);
    this.objectPool.setMaxIdle(this.maxIdle);
    }

  //here i provided two methods one to get the connection and the other to return the connection to the pool

}
```

### connectionProperties.properties

```
uname=xxx
pwd=xxxx
host=xxx
java.naming.provider.url=someurl
```

### applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="connectionPool" class="com.mycompany.ConnectionPool">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionsFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionsFactory" class="com.mycompany.ConnectionsFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="propertyFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="propertyFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>  
                <value>classpath:conf/connectionProperties.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Above cofiguration is working fine without any issues.
So far i have only one properties file and all the properties are belongs to one geography.
Now i need to change the properties file to support multiple geographies and each geography has its properties as below.

### connectionProperties_US.properties

```
uname=xxx
pwd=xxxx
host=xxx
```

### connectionProperties_UK.properties

```
uname=xxx
pwd=xxxx
host=xxx
```

### connectionProperties_Germany.properties

```
uname=xxx
pwd=xxxx
host=xxx
```

Comment: use different names may be? uname_Germany, etc?

Comment: Eugene, Thanx for ur reply. I cannot change the keys in property file. Because the external system takes the values with that keys only...if it has any other key names then it ignores...

Comment: Eugene, any suggestions? Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [SPEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions). for example you could have a static method that returns the locale and use that value to define your property filename.

```
<value>classpath:conf/connectionProperties_#{ T(java.util.Locale).getCountry()}.properties</value>
```